# ¿Como realizar despliegue de una aplicación desarrollada en next js 13.x y backend codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, typescript, axios, codeigniter-4, nextjs13

Mi pregunta es tengo una aplicación desarrollada en next js 13 y el backend con codeigniter 4, quiero hacer el despliegue a cpanel, cabe recalcar que el cpanel no tiene para crear la aplicación node, como he visto en algunos videos. Realizo el npm run build, este último me genera una carpeta que le doy por nombre dist. La subo y todo solo esa, el primer problema es: no me genera algunos estilos css importantes, segundo no tengo conocimiento de como subir el backend junto al frontend. Les agradecería me pudiera ayudar esta excelenticima gran comunidad. De antemano Gracias.

Podrían por favor indicarme como realizarlo de manera correcta o algún documento donde pudiera apoyarme, ya que he visto un montón de videos pero ninguno lo resuelve.